# What would be the simplest way to connect a smartpy contract to an oracle tracking the XTZ/USD pair?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, oracle

I see there's a smartpy chainlink oracle example and a github repo for Harbinger. I briefly looked at the code and it appears they are for setting up Oracles + clients. Are there any existing XTZ/USD Oracle quorums that can be plugged into and is there a good tutorial to follow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chainlink price feed is currently being finalized.
More information is coming about it in a few weeks.

Comment: what about the Harbinger oracles? are those useable now?

Comment: I didn't include them in my answer because my understanding is that they are usable but they are not quorum oracles. I'll let the Hover Labs confirm or not.